# How to remove fish from tanks in Megaquarium?

Tags: megaquarium

How to get rid of fish in Megaquarium, instead of moving them to a different tank?

Answer (score 2):

Click on a tank to see its details and fish, then press the **X** key of your keyboard, it enables selling the fish and decorations. Then left click on the fish and decorations you want to sell.